# My dynamic website is not responding to specific button click

Tags: javascript, html, json, logic, client-server

whilst making the function on my dynamic single page web app which allows the user to upload images I have come across quite a large issue. In order to simplify and find the root of the issue, I have simplified by function. All the function is meant to do right now is take values from a form and display them in the console however at the moment it is just seems to restart the page and return to the home page. This error is so confusing as I have already programmed functions for some of my other pages which work completely fine. I used a similar code structure to those functions for this function but it just did nothing. I understand that the amount of code I'm posting may not be sufficient to understand the error but I don't feel comfortable posting heavy chunks of my code on here , but am willing to show them over chat. Thank you. This is my code:
**client.js**

```
.
.//code for other pages functions
.
async function ImageHandler(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name =document.getElementById('username').value;
    var title =document.getElementById('titleofimage').value;
    console.log(name);
    console.log(title);
    imgform.reset();

}

const imgform= document.getElementById("image-form");
imgform.addEventListener("submitImage", ImageHandler);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <main>
        <div class='Page' id='pictures'>
            <h1>pictures</h1>
            <form id='image-form'>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='username'>username</label>
                    <input class='form-control' name='name' id='username' required>
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='titleofimage'>Tile</label>
                    <input class='form-control' name='title' id='titleofimage >
                </div>
                <input type='file' id='image' required><br>
                <button type='submitImage' class='btn btn-primary'>submit Image</button>
            </form>            
        </div>
     .(//other pages code)
     .
     .
  </main>
  <script src='client.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You mentioned "This error is so confusing", can you share the error? Are you seeing any other errors or warnings in the browser console?

Are all of your network calls resolving successfully?

Have you tried adding some trace level logs at the top and bottom of the event listener?

What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: @EthanRadford there is no error as such just that whenever I press the submit image button it seems to refresh the entire website rather than log the values to console and reset  the form.I am using google chrome. The error is so confusing because I have written entire client server functions which are still working fine and this function is written in the same way as them so I don't understand why it doesn't work. Im not sure what your other suggestions mean

Comment: Your `console.log` statements do not appear until halfway down the listener. Have you tried placing any console output statements as the very first line in you listener? That should at least tell you if your listener is executing and failing or not executing at all. WRT to the absence of errors, if the page is refreshing, your console and network logs will clear out on the page load, unless you've specifically selected options to preserve them. Are you preserving logs currently?

Comment: @EthanRadford I added a console.log at the start of the function and I think the function is not being called at all as it still doesn't log the message I added to the start.

Comment: The event name should be `"submit"` and no such type "submitImage" for a button.

Comment: Nice catch! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an apostrophe in one of the inputs:
`titleofimage' >`

As @charlietfl mentioned, to submit the form, you can only use the button type `submit`, `submitImage` will not work. You could also omit it, as a button within a form will always submit it.

The same thing needs to be corrected in the js File, `imgform.addEventListener("submit", ImageHandler)` instead of `..submitImage...`